# An Android view that is both expandable and column aligned

Tags: android, user-interface

I am looking for something that is both Expandable like a listView, but also has aligned columns like TableView. I can put a TableView inside a ListView, but then I have individual tables and the column width should be as big as it needs to be to wrap the content.

Comment: Expandable implies that each row can be expanded into multiple other rows. Is that what you mean, or do you just want it to scroll like a listview?

Comment: Like you said each like can be expanded. But the group header doesn't need to have columns, just the elements within that group.